# Debugging GLX app - sluggish window doesn't repaint

Tags: debian, x11, glx

I am porting an OpenGL application to Linux (Debian Jesse core, using GLX, X11 and Xfree86, GL 3.0 via Mesa 10.3.2). I'm stuck on a rendering problem that I don't fully understand (description follows), and I have exhausted the methods of debugging that I know how to use. My question is, how do I approach debugging this? Is there a tool I can use to inspect performance, a log file I can look at, a development library I can install and set breakpoints on, something else?

The symptoms:

- Once the window is instantiated, the window frame is drawn but the window contents are not drawn (I see the desktop background in the window)
- click-drag on title bar to move the window around is sluggish
- Closing the app takes several seconds, but for a very brief instant immediately before the window is destroyed, the correct screen output appears in the window
- Resizing the window to be very small does not improve the sluggishness or display problem
- `top` reveals a max usage of only 2% cpu (most of the time it ranges between 0.3 - 0.7%), memory use rises and falls but stays in a steady range, and the rest of my graphical apps suffer a little lag but the rest of the system is fairly snappy. Here's a snapshot from `top`:

```
top - 01:09:42 up  3:43,  3 users,  load average: 0.31, 0.12, 0.12
Tasks:   1 total,   1 running,   0 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.3 us,  0.4 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.2 id,  0.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:  16411604 total,  1342704 used, 15068900 free,    47860 buffers
KiB Swap:  2783228 total,        0 used,  2783228 free.   752736 cached Mem
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                      
3758 andrew    20   0  145700  25080  16704 R   0.3  0.2   0:02.36 mtexec
```

What I've tried:

- I have run into a similar problem on windows, where the problem was passing a null window handle to a `SwapBuffers` call. I ran `gdb` with a breakpoint on my `glXSwapBuffers` call and made sure the same thing is not happening now.
- Tracing through the window creation code using `gdb` making sure that the `Display*` and `Window` instances are not null and not being changed.
- Redrawing and not-redrawing on `Expose` and `ConfigureNotify` events. Removing the redraw code does not seem to have any effect on the problem.
- In case it matters, I am using GLEW, but not for context creation. I get a function pointer to `glXCreateContextAttribsARB` via `glXGetProcAddress`.

Comment: Does the application's memory usage grow while it's running?

Comment: I'm watching it right now, memory is rising and falling in very low increments, and does not appear to be growing over long period of time.

Comment: I made some progress on this problem. I removed the XFree86 code I was using to enumerate the video modes, and now I get screen output. I also believe that another problem was lurking in my old code, that a shallow copy of an X11 `Window` object caused some of the problem. For reference, this example is working for me: https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/165856-Minimal-GLX-OpenGL3-0-example

Comment: I'm going to leave this question up while I narrow down the code problem and paste the offending code back to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to my question about how to debug this problem: check that your display enumeration is providing a `GLXFramebufferConfig` that is actually compatible with your X11 display. If you are mixing `glX` with `Xf86` library calls, try just using the `glX` to get the program up and running. A good resource that explains the details is the [Programming OpenGL in Linux: GLX and Xlib](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Programming_OpenGL_in_Linux:_GLX_and_Xlib) guide.